# How to get length of this Array in Python? Pyramid framework

Tags: python, arrays, pyramid

I am trying to get the lengths of the following Arrays in Pyramid.

[image]

When I try this below

```
${outbox_details.details['declined']} 
${outbox_details.details['accepted']}
${outbox_details.details['pending']}
```

I see what I think is an empty Array getting generated in the HTML:
[image]

Full Markup for above:

```
<li>
    <img src="..." alt="Denied"/>${outbox_details.details['declined']} denied
</li>
<li>
    <img src="..." alt="Accepted"/>${outbox_details.details['accepted']} accepted
</li>
<li>
    <img src="..." alt="Pending"/>${outbox_details.details['pending']} pending
</li>
```

I've tried .length and .len, but they all error out in PyCharm:

```
${outbox_details.details.length.(['declined'])} 
${outbox_details.details.len['declined']}
${outbox_details.details.len(['declined'])}
```

If you are a Python, or back-end developer, how would you get the length of the accepted, declined or pending arrays?

Comment: "I don't code in Python" is not a good way to start a Python-related question. You should at least try to understand what you are working with, otherwise you are not able to ask the right question.

Comment: @sphere Pyramid, using Mako Templates. Just needed to get the length of the Array. Pretty simple task, I just didn't know the sytax, also got errors while trying the syntax I found on different answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but:

```
myArr = [1,2,3]
len(myArr) # returns 3
```

Equivalently, this should work as the length of the "declined" array

```
len(outbox_details.details['declined'])
```

Protip: While there are indeed arrays in python (in numpy, etc), the usual data structure is a `list`, implemented as a dynamic array

Comment: Thanks that worked! I didn't think about treating the whole path as the Array, was trying to just use Len over the last item

Answer (score 3):

You can assess the length of a Python array one of two ways (that I know of):

```
arrayVariable = ["hello", 3, "sample"]
arrayVariable.__len__()  # method number 1
len(arrayVariable)       # method number 2
```

Both will return the length of the data structure. Hope that helps!

Comment: Why would someone use `__len__()`? This is ther "inwards" interface.

Comment: That's different syntax for one method.  `len()` calls the `__len__(self)` method of the object passed if one exists.